# Isn't this correct in C++?

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int szam,tart;
    cout << "Num=";
    cin >> szam;
    while(szam!=tart){
        tart=szam;
        cout << "Now insert a number which is not " << tart << "\n Your number is=";
        cin >> szam;
        if(szam==tart)
            cout << "And you failed.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't this code correct? My teacher keeps saying that it's not correct because I should've called a value for "tart" variable, like "cin >> tart" .

Please answer asap.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Please write the text in english. But i guess the program should run until you type in the value stored in again. Thus you should never change szam, only tart

Comment: Go through each line in the code with a debugger or pen and pencil and see what the value of each variable is and you will understand. Also try to run your program and look at the printout, does it look right?

Comment: The program is asking the user to write a number, which is not the one entered before. If he writes the number which was entered before, the program ends.

Comment: Yes, it looks right. But my teacher is saying that this isn't a global variable and it gets 0 as value  only with luck.

Comment: The program is also running well.

Comment: Then see the answers given below.

Comment: @BalazsLehel Teacher correct! You need to initialize `tart` variable into integer value before use.

Answer (score 8):

Since `tart` has not been assigned to before it is used (in the compare), the result of the initial comparison is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

It is ill-formed gcc will even give you a diagnostic:

```
main.cpp:13:15: warning: 'tart' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     while(szam!=tart){
           ~~~~^~~~~~
```

using uninitialized variable is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but you should give tart a value. Otherwise, it gets initialized with a random one.

Comment: You're right. But I think that the value of tart at the beginning of the program doesn't matter since it will get the value of szam variable.

Answer (score 1):

"int tart;" does create a variable named tart of type int, however its value is not set (undefined), meaning if you use it, it can and (most of the times) will cause errors.

Comment: Yes, but later it will get the szam variable''s value, not ?

Comment: Yes -later. After you've tested for it in: "while(szam!=tart) {". So you make the mistake of testing for it, which will give a bad result, and then you correct it. The error will still happen.

Comment: [FYI] That is just a minimum range.  There is nothing stopping an implementation to make `int` 64 bits.

Comment: Or set it a trap value which will lead to crash when used in any way, or use ESP powers allowed by standard and set it to `szam` value, whichever this would be, making comparison always false...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int szam;
    int tart=0;//need to initialize or need to call  cin >> tart;
    cout << "Num=";
    cin >> szam;
    while(szam!=tart){
        tart=szam;
        cout << "Now insert a number which is not " << tart << "\n Your number is=";
        cin >> szam;
        if(szam==tart)
            cout << "And you failed.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```